# issue with postun scripts when renaming munin package

Tags: rpm, yum, rpmbuild, munin

I have two issues that i would like to figure out a solution to:

I am renaming the munin 2.0 package and in the SPEC file for the RPM I have to obsolete the original munin packages.

When replacing an existing 1.x munin package as part of the postun scriptlets of munin-node it removes the munin user.

```
postuninstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then
    /usr/sbin/userdel munin || logger -t munin/rpm "User \"munin\" could not be deleted."
#       /usr/sbin/groupdel munin || logger -t munin/rpm "Group \"munin\" could not be deleted."
fi
```

When I am replacing an existing munin 2.0 package the postun deletes the contents of the plugins directory.

```
postuninstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
if [ "$1" = "0" ]; then
   [ -d /etc/munin/plugins ] && \
find /etc/munin/plugins/ -maxdepth 1 -type l -print0 | \
   xargs -0 rm || :
fi
```

Since yum installs the new package and then runs the posts for the old package and `$1 = 0` in both cases it will run the scripts after my rpms have been installed. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of would be a hack where you copy out the contents in your `%pre` into another location, and then `%trigger` on the uninstall of the other package to put them back. Not the best form, but it might work. Also requires that you are installed before the uninstall.